# Pythonic way to manage multiple callbacks

Tags: python, sublimetext2

I'm writing a small plugin for Sublime Text 2. The workflow requires me to prompt the user multiple times to get a series of answers.

I'm using show_input_panel to get input, and I'm defining a function to collect each answer.

Here is a sample of the code:

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class SampleCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):

    #############################
    # Main
    #############################

    def run(self, edit):
        self.edit = edit

        self.window = sublime.active_window()

        # first prompt
        self.window.show_input_panel('First question', '', self.on_first_answer, None, None)

    #############################
    # Async Handlers
    #############################

    def on_first_answer(self, answer_a):
        self.answer_a = answer_a
        self.window.show_input_panel('Second question', '', self.on_second_answer, None, None)

    def on_second_answer(self, answer_b):
        self.answer_b = answer_b
        self.window.show_input_panel('Third question', '', self.on_third_answer, None, None)

    def on_third_answer(self, answer_c):
        answers = self.answer_a + self.answer_b + answer_c
        sublime.message_dialog('Your answers: ' + answers)
```

I'm new to Python, so I was wondering if there was a better way to organize these multiple callbacks.

In JavaScript I'd start using anonymous closures, which would spare me from storing each answers on the object.
And when closures are not enough, I'd try something like promises.

What's the best way to manage a scenario like that in Python?

Comment: Please, do **not** post code externally. Your question should be useful to others in the future, and not depend on an external service. I've posted your code here for you, there is no need to use a gist.

Comment: However there are exceptions when I think you should post your code externally with a subset included on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`generator.send` is very useful for this kind of thing:

```
import sublime

def prompt_sequence(g):
    def progress(result):
        try:
            progress.caption, progress.initial_text = g.send(result)
            sublime.active_window().show_input_panel(
                progress.caption,
                progress.initial_text,
                progress, None, None
            )
        except StopIteration:
            pass

    progress(None)

def foo():
    first_answer = yield ('First question', '')
    second_answer = yield ('Second question', '')
    third_answer = yield ('Thirdquestion', '')

    sublime.message_dialog('Your answers: ' + answers)

prompt_sequence(foo())
```

Or written another way (may not work):

```
def self_referencing(gen_func):
    @functools.wraps(gen_func)
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        g = gen_func(lambda: g, *args, **kwargs)
        return g
    return wrapped



class SampleCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    @self_referencing
    def get_things(gen_self, self):
        sublime.active_window().show_input_panel(
            'First question', '',
            gen_self().send, None, None
        )
        result_a = yield
        sublime.active_window().show_input_panel(
            'Second question', '',
            gen_self().send, None, None
        )
        result_b = yield
        sublime.active_window().show_input_panel(
            'Third question', '',
            gen_self().send, None, None
        )
        result_c = yield
```

Comment: this (the first version) is nice, but if you are not familiar with generators it's going to help you know that the initial send of a None is necessary to "prime" the generator (trigger the first yield) and that the *second* send is what sets the first answer (in other words, read `answer = yield question` from right to left).  once you get that, the code seems much more logical.